# Filename of class Varien_Data_Collection_Filesystem getting renamed to Filesystem.php.suspected

Tags: magento-1.9, security, server, ce-1.9.1.1

We're getting the following error:

> Magento Fatal error: Class' Varien_Data_Collection_Filesystem' not found

Checking the cause of the error, the `Filesystem.php` file is is renamed to `Filesystem.php.suspected`. Manually renaming it back to `Filesystem.php` fixes the issue but everyday we need to manually rename it since it is constantly being renamed back to `Filesystem.php.suspected`.

I've googled as to what causes the error but still no luck. I am quite sure that there is something that is renaming this file but don't know where to start since i'm fairly new to magento.

Magento ver. 1.9.1.1

Comment: I suspect ;) that there is a virus/malware scanner of some sort running on your system that feels this file is not safe. I can imagine this with a file containing all sorts of file system operations. You should set your software to ignore this file.

Comment: I am having similar situation. The above file is getting changed to .suspected everyday. I verified and found that I do not have any malware scanner installed. So what will be causing this change in my case. And yes, I verified the original file with the file on my server and there is no change.

Answer (score 6):

As @7ochem pointed out, this looks like something a malware scanner would do, that either you or your hoster installed.

Please compare the renamed file to the original Magento 1.9.1.1 file (you can download it from here: https://raw.githubusercontent.com/OpenMage/magento-mirror/1.9.1.1/lib/Varien/Data/Collection/Filesystem.php) and see **if there are any differences**.

**If not**, the alert was a false positive, configure the malware scanner to ignore it, or ask your hoster to do so.

**If yes, you have been hacked.** Please read 
https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/78866/243 and take action immediately.

Comment: I've verified that there are no differences with the file in concern and the ones in the mirror. My magento installation is on a digitalocean ubuntu droplet and i am not sure if the previous dev has installed a malware scanner. How can i check for the default scanner?

Comment: I don't know. Ask Digitalocean.

Comment: have same problem. do you fix it?