# unable to edit Static blocks and Cms Pages

Tags: magento-1.9, cms

I am not able to edit the static blocks, throws an error on click

```
Fatal error: Class 'Varien_Data_Collection_Filesystem' not found in public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Widget/Model/Widget/Config.php on line 85
```

When i click on CMS pages it showing like below image

[image: when i click on cms pages]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check whether this file exist in your application.

```
 lib/Varien/Data/Collection/Filesystem.php
```

If not present, place a fresh copy of that file in that location. You can ***[find one here](https://github.com/OpenMage/magento-mirror/blob/magento-1.9/lib/Varien/Data/Collection/Filesystem.php)***.

Also ***[check-out this thread](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/83275/filename-of-class-varien-data-collection-filesystem-getting-renamed-to-filesyste)*** and make sure there is no vulnerabilities in your applicaion