# Magento 1.9 - When I open my site opens a page of advertising

Tags: magento-1.9

my problem of my site is this...when i open my site opens a page of advertising. How can I eliminate this malware from my site?

Comment: reset your browser will remove the adds or install ad  blocker

Comment: So it's only problem of browser and not of my site?

Comment: are you getting adds with your site or just a add can you please update question with your image

Comment: Yes, when opens my site or a random category open advertising page. This is the link... **[LINK REMOVED DUE TO MALWARE] - benmarks**

Comment: Sounds like the site was hacked and somebody included advertising, **possibly malware**. I won't click that link and would advise anybody else not to do as well.

Comment: Possible source of the popups: The "Miscellanneous Scripts" configuration. Related: http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/115753/probably-security-issue

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From url which you mentioned in the above comments it looks that your computer is infected by malware to remove it you can refer following link.

https://malwaretips.com/blogs/remove-adware-popup-ads/

also have a look on your site which is available at our end as attached in image their is no virus in your site it is your PC issue.

[image]

Hope this helps you.

Comment: are u getting the same output which i shared you.

Comment: Perfect man!!! Now i understand the problem. Thank you for the response. :)

Comment: Exscusme man, but i check my pc right now with my antivirus but i have not found any virus or malware. But you've tried to entry in categories of my site with the same results right? Thank you for the help.