# MageReport: "Malicious code found, you are vulnerable" - possible false positive?

Tags: magento-1, security, patches, enterprise-1.14

I get a warning for one of our sites on magereport.com about the famous Credit Cart Hijack:

> Credit Card Hijack detected?

[image: Credit Card Hijack detected?]

But there is nothing added to "Miscellaneous HTML" or "Miscellaneous Scripts" configurations, and when I check the HTML source code, I don't find *any* additional scripts that should not be there. Searching in the minified JS for remarkable parts of the [example](https://www.byte.nl/blog/widespread-credit-card-hijacking-discovered) also yields nothing. Patches were always applied immediately.

I watched the Firebug netwok tab while going through the checkout, entering credit card details and going to the next step. No requests were made except to Magento and to the payment provider.

---

Since the message from Magereport has a question mark, I am wondering:

**Does anybody know of false positives, where harmless scripts were identified as malicious? Or am I looking in the wrong places?**

Comment: Never seen a false positive before, would you mind sharing the address in private ?

Comment: Hi Fabian & Raphael! MageReport scans for runtime Javascript detection of checkout pages, which turns out to be malicious in 99.998% of the cases ;) But perhaps you have legitimate code in place. Feel free to share the site with me in a PM or code@magereport.com

Comment: I'm the 0.002% - as we found out it was indeed a false positive from the MageReport heuristic, which should find new variations of the malware, but was triggered by custom code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The part of the hack that is easily identifiable (whether as JS or in the PHP files) is the use of `SESSIID` as a cookie.

The cookie can be set via a JS or via PHP.

Thus, the first thing I would check in your case is your browser cookies while doing a purchase.

Go through the checkout process and check your cookies.

If you see a cookie named `SESSIID` then you're probably affected by the hack.

To check the files you could probably run:

```
grep -ri "SESSIID" .
```

On your Magento folder and see what comes up.

Regarding the database, I reckon you need to look in the following tables for the `SESSIID` string:

- `core_config_data`
- `cms_block`
- `cms_page`

Comment: Thanks! Good news is, there is no `SESSIID` cookie. Only one that I don't recognize, `frontend_cid`, but it's probably related to some third-party service. I'm checking it out now.

Comment: @fschmengler great definitely a good news I'm pretty sure you're safe in that case

Comment: `www/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Session/Abstract/Varien.php:            $secureCookieName = $sessionName . '_cid';` - OK, that's core Magento :)

Comment: @fschmengler yeah I remember working on something related a while back,  can't recall what is was though

Comment: Thanks again, that helped a lot. I'll leave the question open for a while in case somebody knows more about the "why"

Comment: @fschmengler yeah that'd be interesting to find out, maybe contact Byte directly via the support and they could enlight us

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/40892/discussion-between-raphael-at-digital-pianism-and-fschmengler).

Comment: Anything changed since then ? I have this issue on my Magento, tried almost everything I found on internet .... with no luck, all the patches applied, all the code checked ..... maybe it is not really a problem ? What if I'm using a payment method which actually not allow me to store any data but customer is redirected from the page like a SagePay, is it still potentially danger ?

Answer (score 0):

It is a false positive from TinyMCE.
My fix: https://github.com/etripbikes/m1/commit/2a3d35