# I got hacked - Magento 1.7.0.1 problem when applying patch

Tags: magento-1.7, security, patches, magento-1.7.0.1, ce-1.7.0.1

I have a store running magento 1.7.0.1 and I got hacked. Someone accessed the admin page - and added a paypal account, probably using an XSS vulnerability. I applied the patches SUPEE-1533, SUPEE-5344, SUPEE-5994, SUPEE-6285 and SUPEE-6482 with no problems (I think), but when I try to install SUPEE-6788 and SUPEE-7405 all the products disappear from the front page. (I have a backup)

I don't have SSH access and for that reason I followed [this](https://magentary.com/kb/install-supee-7405-without-ssh/) tutorial.

I was wondering, what patches to install for magento 1.7.0.1 in order to solve the vulnerabilities?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, just in case it is not obvious: **Patching a hacked site does not solve the hack**. You prevent further hacks, which is important, but as the server is already compromised there could be more hacks and backdoors that you are not aware of yet. See also: [Probably security issue](https://magento.stackexchange.com/q/115753/243)

> Your customer data is at risk! Take the site offline immediately and then start investigating the PHP code and other files.

About the disappearing products: After [supee-6788](/questions/tagged/supee-6788) block types must be added to a whitelist before using them in the CMS. Your theme seems to use custom block types for the home page. Check your home page CMS content and look for `{{block type="..."}}` directives.

Then see here how to do add them to the white list: [APPSEC-1057 How to add variables or blocks to the white list tables](https://magento.stackexchange.com/q/87466/243)

Comment: Thank you very much, I solved the problem. I had to go on system > permissions > blocks and add the blocks that was hidden.

Answer (score 0):

scan your site with this [link](https://www.magereport.com/), so it will show what patches are still left.

also you can check this for what patches need to install : [link](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1MTbU9Bq130zrrsJwLIB9d8qnGfYZnkm4jBlfNaBF19M/edit#gid=192164130)

**APPSEC-212
SUPEE-1533
SUPEE-5344
SUPEE-5994
SUPEE-6285
SUPEE-6482
SUPEE-6788
SUPEE-7405
SUPEE-7405 v1.1**

Comment: I'm using it, although it seems not to be updated, it doesn't include the 7405 patch verification and the 6788 doesn't verify. - Now I don't know if the patch is working or the website.

Comment: @molunoluda glad that you found solution.....

Comment: Thank you - A better alternative for security checking: https://www.magereport.com